# Rails 4 assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx

These tags:

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %> <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

are resulting in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/application.css"> <script src="/javascripts/application.js">
```

instead of the fingerprinted links.

I am running my app on Ubuntu Ruby on Rails on 14.04 (Nginx + Unicorn) on digitalocean. I have done rake:assets:precompile. I have also added require "sprockets/railtie" in application.rb

Comment: Probably you haven't set the staging to `:production`, yet.

Comment: I am a beginner. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your rails console

```
 rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```